# Maven filtering on resources stored in dependencies

Tags: spring, maven

Is it possible to have maven filtering applied on resources (such as spring files) that are stored in dependencies?

A spring file in one of my dependent jars uses the property ${project.artifactId}.  How can I apply filtering to this spring file so I can import the resource in my local spring file?

Comment: Are you trying to filter a spring file in another jar? If so, can you unzip the jar?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to filter a spring file in another jar.  The jar is grabbed as a dependency from my repository.

Comment: Unzipping the jar is not really that elegant. I have also come across this problem before and it's something you end up hitting once in a while with Spring. When this happens for me, I try to figure out a proper way to refactor the code, if it's in my reach.

This is a good question and I think a feature request should be filed on Spring's JIRA.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You can unpack the jar first by using the [unpack goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) in the maven dependency plugin.

You can then apply filtering using the [resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/).

Comment: The jar already is being unpacked; the spring file is being unloaded to the classpath in my target directory.  However, filtering the target directory didn't work because the filtering occurred before the files were moved over.  Even if I modified the filtering to occur after unpacking, filtering the target directory seems like a very bad solution.