# How to provide Maven project properties as a service?

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, properties-file

**Context**

I have a Maven module (let's call it **Service**). 
It uses Spring-Boot (non-web environment) `@ConfigurationProperties` to load configuration from one or more `.properties` files. On runtime the configuration is stored in a singleton class `MyConfiguration.java` with getters for all known properties.

The goal is to have other modules / projects (let's call it **Apps**) which have their individual `.properties` file and use **Service** to automatically populate the configuration. Further, **Service** exports via `src/main/resources` a `root-settings.properties` which contains placeholders for  project properties that are required by all **Apps**.
These should be hopefully populated via the Maven filtering mechanism derived from project properties based on the `pom.xml`

One such property is the version. In **Service** a test verifies that it is replaced by Maven with the following setup:

**root-settings.properties**

`applicationVersion=${project.version}`

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
</build>
```

**Question**

How to configure or re-design **Services** so that a single dependency from **Apps** and a call to `MyConfiguration.getInstance().getApplicationVersion()` provides the version of **Apps**?

As it currently stands, when **Apps** has a dependency on **Service** the `root-settings.properties` as shown above is present in its classpath. However there are still two problems:

- `${project.version}`  is not replaced during resource filtering because `root-settings.properties` is in an external .jar. I would need to configure another goal to unpack the .jar and hope for resource filtering to apply afterwards.
- Each **App** would need to add resource filtering to its configuration making the use of **Services** less convenient. I am looking for a solution that in the best case does not need any modification of **Apps** `pom.xml`

**Related Questions**
In order of relevance these two topics could be slightly related:
 - [Maven filtering on resources stored in dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313007/maven-filtering-on-resources-stored-in-dependencies)
 - [Filter maven resources with filter-file from external dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047152/filter-maven-resources-with-filter-file-from-external-dependency)

Comment: You should be using `Spring-Cloud-Config` https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html

Comment: The best I can suggest to use the [templating-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/) which can create a class from a template which can contain such information...(Example: https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-deployer-extension/blob/master/pom.xml)..